# how to get current wishlist in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, wishlist

I am using magento enterprise and i am working in wishlist there is a function in core at path

> C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\baab.bh\app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\Helper\Data.php

```
getWishlist()
```

When i am calling this function to get wishlist from front-end **phtml** file its giving me the correct wishlist but when i am calling this function from **controller** its giving me the default wishlist only, not the current wishlist here is the code of this function

```
public function getWishlist()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_wishlist)) {
            if (Mage::registry('shared_wishlist')) {
                $this->_wishlist = Mage::registry('shared_wishlist');
            } elseif (Mage::registry('wishlist')) {
                $this->_wishlist = Mage::registry('wishlist');
            } else {
                $this->_wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist');
                if ($this->getCustomer()) {
                    $this->_wishlist->loadByCustomer($this->getCustomer());
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->_wishlist;
    }
```

I am calling it with same code but it behaves differently from front-end **phtml** file than it does from **controller**. How can i get current wishlist from controller as well.

Comment: In which controller you are trying to get wishlist?

Comment: i have a function in custom controller and i am calling it through ajax. i also put this function in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\baab.bh\app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\controllers\IndexController.php 
but when i am calling it through ajax its not giving me current wishlist